# How to build Avro Hive table based on avro files with schema inside?

Tags: hive, schema, avro

We have a dataset in Avro format with schema inside each Avro file.

I want to build Hive table on top of these files,

I got the below recommendation from an old question asked here in the community:

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sampe_table STORED AS AVRO LOCATION 'hdfs:///user/hive/;

But whenever I try it I get always the error:

```
 java.lang.Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException Encountered AvroSerdeException determining schema. Returning signal schema to indicate problem: Neither avro.schema.literal nor avro.schema.url specified, can't determine table schema)
```

Any Suggestions? or do you know any online tool that can split Schema from the file?

Answer (score 1):

First generate an `avsc` file and use that file to create a table

```
create external table myavro 
stored as avro 
location '/user/cloudera/myavro'
tblproperties('avro.schema.url' = 'file:///home/cloudera/myavsc.avsc')
```

To generate `avsc` from the existing avro data files, use `avro-tools`, like this

```
avro-tools getschema your_avro_file
```